# My simple chrome extension that prints at a certain URL is not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Export HumbleBundle Library TEST",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "icons": {
  },
  "description": "Store information of all your unredeemed games from  humblebundle.com in JSON file",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://humblebundle.com/home/keys"],
      "js": ["main.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

main.js

```
console.log("jtara1 start");
```

I was in the middle of working on making an extension, but it seems to have stopped loading my script as a developer unpacked extension. Nothing is printed out in the console when I visit https://humblebundle.com/home/keys

[download link for the two files listed above](https://ufile.io/8nbm7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`humblebundle.com` redirects to `www.humblebundle.com` - which is not a specified [matched pattern](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns). Edit the `matches` value to `"*://*.humblebundle.com/*"`, and it should work

Comment: Not sure why this worked, but it fixed my problem. It worked at one point as `"*://humblebundle.com/home/keys"` and my other chrome extension works similarly

Answer (score 0):

Please verify "matches" in "content_scripts" i think the URL pattern is wrong.

Please don't forgot to reload your ext. fro take efface which you made

[image]